# Upload a file in a server with ANDROID

Tags: php, android

I want to upload a file in a server with Android Studio. I have the code, but not working. It's very strangeble. How can I do? This is the code:

```
public void uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {

    HttpURLConnection mHttpURLConnection = null;
    DataOutputStream mOutputStream = null;
    String strLineEnd = "\r\n";
    String strTwoHyphens = "--";
    String strUpLoadServerUri = upLoadServerUri;
    String strBoundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {


        Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :" + sourceFile.getAbsolutePath());

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"+uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);
            }
        });

    }
    else
    {

        try {

            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL(strUpLoadServerUri);

            // Open a HTTP connection to the URL

            mHttpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();
            mHttpURLConnection.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            mHttpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            mHttpURLConnection.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy

            mHttpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            mHttpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection","Keep-Alive");
            mHttpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE","multipart/form-data");
            mHttpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","multipart/form-data;boundary=" + strBoundary);
            mHttpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file",sourceFileUri);

            mOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(mHttpURLConnection.getOutputStream());

            mOutputStream.writeBytes(strTwoHyphens + strBoundary + strLineEnd);
            mOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename="+ sourceFileUri + strLineEnd);

            mOutputStream.writeBytes(strLineEnd);

            // create a buffer of maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {

                mOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            }

            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            mOutputStream.writeBytes(strLineEnd);
            mOutputStream.writeBytes(strTwoHyphens + strBoundary + strTwoHyphens + strLineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            serverResponseCode = mHttpURLConnection.getResponseCode();

            // close the streams //
            fileInputStream.close();
            mOutputStream.flush();
            mOutputStream.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(),ex);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Upload file to server Exception","Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    if (serverResponseCode == 200) {

        Log.d("File Uploaded For ",sourceFileUri + "   Successful");

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                    /*
                    String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                            +" http://www.androidexample.com/media/uploads/"
                            +uploadFileName;

                    //messageText.setText(msg);
                    */

                Toast.makeText(Page1.this, "File Upload Complete.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
    else{
        Log.d("File Uploaded For ",sourceFileUri + "   Failed");

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                    /*
                    String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                            +" http://www.androidexample.com/media/uploads/"
                            +uploadFileName;

                    //messageText.setText(msg);
                    */

                Toast.makeText(Page1.this, "File Upload Failed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }


}
```

And this is the code PHP. I have a server with this file php:

```
<?php
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], './'.$_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'])) {
  echo "Success";

 } else{
  echo "fail";
 ?>
```

Comment: `but not working`. That is a very bad description. Please take the efort to tell what happens and what not.

Comment: Where do you call uploadFile()?

Comment: You did not even tell which echo you get from php. Or if you get an echo at all. Not working? What is not working?

Comment: You did not tell which Logs you see or which toast.

Comment: I use Api 23(Android Marshmellow) and I have a server Altervista. When I work with the function uploadfile, It gives me the file it uploaded with succes. But in the server 
does not appear the file

Comment: That code tells itself that it is successfull. But it tells nothing. Wrong code. You should read the echo from php. Php tells you if there is "Success" or "fail". That 200 comes from the webserver. Not from your php script.